# Construct uncountably infinite many infinite sets, whose pair wise intersection is finite, and union of all of them is the set of natural numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Construct uncountably infinite many infinite sets, whose pair wise intersection is finite, and union of all of them is the set of natural numbers.

I have been trying to find a bijection between $N$ and all rational numbers in $[0,1]$.But I am not getting the rigor.

Comment: It's usually a good idea [to search](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/162387) before posting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure this is a duplicate, because the (admittedly trivial) requirement "union of all of them is the set of natural numbers" is absent from the old question.

Comment: @bof: You're joking, right?